# Conky-Manager on Ubuntu 20.10

Tags: 20.10, conky

I have recently installed Ubuntu 20.10 and I can't get the Conky Manager to run. It worked fine on 20.04LTS. I am just using the standard "Gotham" template.

If I try running it via the terminal, this happens:

```
mike@mike-hpprobook450g1:~$ conky -c ~/.conky/Gotham/Gotham
conky: Syntax error (/home/mike/.conky/Gotham/Gotham:1: syntax error near 'yes') while reading config file. 
conky: Assuming it's in old syntax and attempting conversion.
conky: [string "..."]:159: attempt to call a nil value (global 'loadstring')
```

I've fiddled a bit with it... changing "yes" to "true", for example However, that hasn't helped.
What's changed? Has anyone out there tried this? I have tried it with Ubuntu Studio (KDE) as well as Ubuntu (Gnome) and it just won't run on 20.10.

Conky Manager 2.4, and conky 1.11.6 compiled 2020-08-17 for Linux x86_64
(edit - here's the code)

```
use_xft yes
xftfont 123:size=8
xftalpha 0.1
update_interval 1
total_run_times 0

own_window yes
own_window_type normal
own_window_transparent yes
own_window_hints undecorated,below,sticky,skip_taskbar,skip_pager
own_window_colour 000000
own_window_argb_visual no
own_window_argb_value 0

double_buffer yes
#minimum_size 250 5
#maximum_width 500
draw_shades no
draw_outline no
draw_borders no
draw_graph_borders no
default_color white
default_shade_color red
default_outline_color green
alignment top_middle
gap_x 0
gap_y 20
no_buffers yes
uppercase no
cpu_avg_samples 2
net_avg_samples 1
override_utf8_locale yes
use_spacer yes


minimum_size 0 0
TEXT
${voffset 10}${color EAEAEA}${font GE Inspira:pixelsize=120}${time %I:%M}${font}${voffset -84}${offset 10}${color FFA300}${font GE Inspira:pixelsize=42}${time %d} ${voffset -15}${color EAEAEA}${font GE Inspira:pixelsize=22}${time  %B} ${time %Y}${font}${voffset 24}${font GE Inspira:pixelsize=58}${offset -148}${time %A}${font}
${voffset 1}${offset 12}${font Ubuntu:pixelsize=12}${color FFA300}HD ${offset 9}$color${fs_free /} / ${fs_size /}${offset 30}${color FFA300}RAM ${offset 9}$color$mem / $memmax${offset 30}${color FFA300}CPU ${offset 9}$color${cpu cpu0}%
```

Comment: I suggest you say what version of conky you are running and include all your conky config. Although it might not be anything to do with conky itself. I have found sometimes when you update Ubuntu your hardware `sys` locations can change for example if you are monitoring cpu or temperature it might be `/sys/class/hwmon/hwmon6/temp3_input` before upgrade but something different afterwards. Then conky is referencing a the old non-existent value. So your config may need changing.

Comment: Code included, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like this bug: https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/67557

> conky updated their config format, and uses a lua script to convert
> from the old config, the lua script uses loadstring which was
> deprecated, so after the recent update I got the error: conky: [string
> "..."]:159: attempt to call a nil value (global 'loadstring')
>
> when trying to start conky.
>
> I edited /usr/share/doc/conky-1.11.5_pre/convert.lua and changed
> loadstring to load, and could then convert my conky config to the new
> format and it worked fine.

On my PC I would have to edit `/usr/share/doc/conky-all/convert.lua` to change `loadstring` to `load`

Comment: Thanks codlord, that looks like the problem I'm having. I tried the convert.lua script with mixed results. Until (if) the developer updates Conky Manager, I'll stick to Ubuntu 20.04 or equivalent!

Comment: Thank you! Using this I was able to install lua, edit the convert file, manually run it (successfully!) and enter the brave new world of conkyrc config file formats.

Answer (score 0):

I've got it to work. Get "conky-manager2" from Github. Then convert.lua runs successfully, and the templates load and run correctly. Tested with Gotham and Conky MIUI.